# How to get image size before loading in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image

I am using jQuery+AJAX to upload image and then generate html to show it. After successfully uploading the image, the AJAX gets the image filename. I want to get the image's dimension ratio before actually loading it. Otherwise, if I load the image and use `.width()` and `.height()`, it will return 0 as it will take some time to load the image.

Is there any function in jQuery like `getimagesize(filename)` of PHP?

*** edit ***

Sorry for the confusion! I want a function in js not in PHP, and the function is like `getimagesize(filename)` of PHP.

*** edit again ***

I post the simplified code here:

```
var html = '<img id="photo' +  id + '" src="' + filename + '" />';
$('#photos li:last').html(html);
var e = $('#photo' + id);
(e.width() / e.height() > 1.6) ? e.attr('width', 160): e.attr('height', 100);
```

Problem here is `.width()` and `.height()` are both 0. if using `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`, they are `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var e = $('#photo' + id);
e.load(function() {
   (e.width() / e.height()) > 1.6 ? e.attr('width', 160): e.attr('height', 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the PHP Manual before asking this question? There is a function in PHP which does exactly that, with the exact name you guessed:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I know the PHP function. I need the same function in jQuery.

Comment: Ah! In that case, see the below suggestion, as that'll work within JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

why not passing a json object from the php file I assume you are ussing to upload the image?
like status (uploaded, error, etc), x (width), y (height), etc.

then you could use it in the ajax callback.